# Trigger yaml template multiple times based on the output of task.Variable

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I want to trigger an existing yaml template multiple times from a CI pipeline based on the length of the previous task output.
I have the below

```
- powershell:
  Get the list of user records from the db
  $records

- ${{ each $record in "$records". Split(" ") }}
  template: ./RunTests.yml
  parameters:
    user: $record
```

So from what I read, in documentation and all the posts before, is ${{}} is computed at compile time whereas in my case here, the length of the records variable is not known until we fetch the list from the DB ( runtime).
What can be the workaround for this?

1. would creating a different template, with an array of records as input, and then calling the RunTests.yml from there help? I think I might end up in the same issue.

Is there any other way I could solve this, if the length of the $records variable is not known at the compile time?

Answer (score 0):

As you already noticed you can't do this using template expressions. But you can try strategy. In that way you can in first job gather records and then pass it as variable to matrix definition.

```yaml
jobs:
- job: JobA
  steps:
  - pwsh: |
      #   Get the list of user records from the db
      $json="{'nginx': {'dockerfile': 'nginx'}, 'nginx-alpine': {'dockerfile': 'nginx-alpine'}}"
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=targets;isOutput=true]$json"
    name: setTargets
  - script: echo $(setTargets.targets)
    name: echovar

- job: buildSrc
  dependsOn: JobA
  displayName: Build source
  strategy:
    matrix: $[ dependencies.JobA.outputs['setTargets.targets'] ]
  variables:
    targets: $[ dependencies.JobA.outputs['setTargets.targets'] ]
  steps:
  - pwsh: Write-Host "${{ convertToJson(variables) }}"
    displayName: 'Print all variables via expression'
  - <PUT your template here>
```

Comment: Thanks! the concept of strategy only works at the job level from what I see. Can this be used at a step level?
So, I just want to run a specific step (containing the template) multiple times, and not the whole job ( which contains all the setup)

Comment: You can apply this at step level. And there is no way to run something similar, because it needs to be known at compilation time.